# Remove URL parameter htacces

Tags: .htaccess

I need to remove a parameter in some cases from URL.

The working url's are:

```
mywebpage.com/es/apartments/ or mywebpage.com/es/apartments/apartment1/
```

But some time I need to pass a value and get url like this:

```
mywebpage.com/es/apartments/&param=12345/
```

In this cases, the page are redirected to 404 page.
The code that I have in htaccess refered to this for redirect from other page is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^luxury-apartments/$
RewriteRule ^error404.php$ /es/apartments/? [L,R=301]
```

How I can remove this param and don't get a 404 redirect? I try some codes, but always redirect me to 404 page.

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^(es/apartments/?)&.*$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thx @anubhav, but doesn't work for me, same 404. Can be the last slash after param?

Comment: That rule worked perfectly for me. Most likely you have some conflicting rule in your .htaccess

Comment: This is not a "redirect to 404 page". You simply get a 404 error. Because that requested URL cannot bet mapped into something inside the server side file system. You do not have any redirection in place for that URL. So _most likely_ you want to implement a redirection for this. Did you try?

Comment: Can you please confirm the URL `/es/apartments/&param=12345/` - that looks like a typo? "But some time I need to pass a value" - not sure how we can solve this in `.htaccess`? If we "remove this param" in `.htaccess` then the value won't be passed to your script?

Comment: Normal param is passed as mywebpage.com/es/apartments/?param=12345

Comment: The url work fine if I don't get param: mywebpage.com/es/apartments/. @arkascha

Comment: I don't generate the link with param. It's a google ad link (gdclid), they add the param with '&' and last slash. @MrWhite.